# Forward-Secure AKE based on post-quantum KEM?

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, forward-secrecy, kem

I am looking for authenticated key exchange protocols (AKE) based on a generic key encapsulation mechanism (KEM) and providing full/perfect forward secrecy. Optionally, the protocols should offer external anonymity.
The idea is to plug into the protocol an existing post-quantum KEM such as CRYSTALS Kyber or SABER.

My research brought me to the following protocols, but which are not totally matching the above-mentioned requirements:

- [Boyd–Cliff–Gonza ́lez-Nieto–Paterson Protocol](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1504/IJACT.2009.023466) (simplest one, no authentication via signatures, no full forward secrecy) [image]
- [CRYSTALS Kyber official AKE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) (does not provide full forward secrecy)[image]
- [The following one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/435.pdf) (provides anonymity, but not sure it is providing full forward secrecy) [image]

Comment: You may want to define full/perfect forward secrecy, figure out why (if?) the generic 3-kem construction (your second construction, as used by Kyber) does not achieve it, and then figure out if you care.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you may want to look into the [IKE](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45708-9_10.pdf) protocol framework. It looks like some variants provide PFS. It's stated in terms of DH, but [Pei14](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-319-11659-4_12) shows an IKE-like that works with just CPA-secure KEMs. Please update if you find an answer!

Comment: The third paper cited claims its construction satisfies foward-security. I agree with K.G. that it should be clarified what property the OP needs that's not satisfied by it.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to generically add FS to any AKE. [BN11](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-25516-8_27) describes a compiler. The caveat is that if you permit ephemeral key revelation in your security model (as is usually permitted in the Canetti-Krawczyk model), then you only get weak FS.

Another route: the $\Sigma_0'$ protocol described in [Pei14](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/070) is a generic construction that takes an IND-CPA-secure KEM and produces an AKE with strong FS. (there's some extra nuance about its security, explained [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1933), but that's the main idea)

Finally, as others noted, I think the [last paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/435) you cited does provide an AKE with strong FS.

Answer (score 1):

There is one post-quantum AKE with forward secure, which was [proposed at EuroCrypt 2015](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/589.pdf).

This protocol uses noise flooding technique + Ding's RLWE reconciliation-based key exchange to construct a forward-secure post-quantum AKE, as claimed by authors

> The security is proven in the Bellare-Rogaway model with weak perfect forward secrecy.

Comment: These aren't generic over KEMs though